# How to automatically login from a webapp to another webapp

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, autologin

I have a web-app (let's call it app1),in which I can't even see the source code, and to get into it.I need to do the basic authentication, "user, pass".

Then I am creating another web-app (app2) (which is java/JSF/Icefaces), where you also have to login using user pass (the user and pass from app1 are the same than user and pass from app2).

Sometimes I have to open one app1 window (to fill in some forms, which I do not want to replicate in app2). I have a valid URL for that window/form, BUT, here is the problem, when I call that URL, then app1 first asks for user/pass, and I do NOT want that. I would like something like single sign on. It is just basic authentication (and I have the user pass).

I tried to open a new jsp in app2, and there sendredirect it to app1 trying to do basic authentication, but I cant, I mean, it does not work.

App1 has a REST API, and I can use it from app2 with basic authentication (So that works).

Can someone help me?

Thaks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SSO (Single Sign On)` concept for this. If you want to do it by SSO straight, yes you can follow the SSO modules, provided by some people. Ofcourse you can create your own SSO method, Implement these steps:

1-> Use the `REST/SOAP API` to login to app1. In response, give back a parameter (an encrypted string or something). Store it in some cookie.(In the back, save this parameter against some timeout and user information for eg, in a `HashMap`)

2->While the login happens from second app, send the parameter with the request. If you accept that parameter in backend, try to validate it against `timeout` and may be the user info.Proceed with authentication on success.

you can set the parameter in a `domain level cookie`.,So all process happens in your backend.

Can you try this and let me know?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will have to understand how App1 handles login, for e.g. if it is cookie based then first you need to login using REST and then set a cookie as per the App1 requirement.

[Single Sign On Concept](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/portals.102/a90343/concepts.htm)

[Build A Single Sign On](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-singlesign/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three ways:

1. Session
2. Cookies
3. Filters

In **first** case, you have to *alter* the `App1` code so that it process automatic login from a [Shared session](http://www.fwd.at/tomcat/sharing-session-data-howto.html) of `App2`.

In **second** case, simply do automatic login by checking the cookies set by `App2`..(I am not confident about this one though)

In **Third** case, you have to set a `Filter` in `App1` so that it *by-passes* the login credentials if request came from your `App2` with special *information*.

But for those you have to alter the code of `App1`. You just cannot bypass an authentication process directly. Also it is a good characteristics of your `App1` that does not allow direct access to a secure page without `login` credentials.